# <p> tag getting added to inline macro

Tags: razor, tinymce, umbraco

I am using umbraco 4.7. I have created a razor macro to insert telephone number in my rich text editor. Whenever i add the macro in the RTE, `<p>` tags are added around the macro automatically. I tried removing the extra `<p>` tags by editing the html but as soon as I click on save, the `<p>` tags are added again. I tried installing this [package](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/-remove-empty-paragraph-tags-from-tiny-mce)

but it didn't solve my problem. I have tried setting the `<TidyEditorContent>False</TidyEditorContent>` and checking the forced_root_block : 'p' but none of these could solve the problem.

Any pointers to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue, and the RTE causes a number of headaches for maintaining the integrity  of your web page. The whole "should we include paragraph tags or not?" question is a difficult one, as it is fine to remove them when only inserting a single paragraph of text, but what if the content editor decides to add more, and you are stripping out the first and last P tags?

Bearing in mind that the CSS for a site will always need to support whatever you choose, the best option is to edit the configuration file to make TinyMCE omit the P tags. To do this, you need to edit the /config/tinyMceConfig.config file. This has two interesting sections at the bottom.  contains allowed HTML tags, and the  of course contains the opposite.

If you look in the valid elements list of comma separated values, you should see a value **#p[id|style|dir|class|align]**. Taking note of **EXACTLY** how this is formatted, you should be able to move it into the invalid elements section. Put it after the default **font** tag, with a comma preceding it of course.

Restart IIS and try entering your content in the RTE. When you publish, then view the output, you should see that the string in the RTE has had the paragraph tags stripped.

One final option is to strip the paragraph tags from the output. There are many new ways of doing this, but for your Razor version I would use something like:

```
@Html.Raw(umbraco.library.RemoveFirstParagraphTag(value.ToString()))
```

This idea is covered in [another StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122802/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-rich-text-editor-in-umbraco-razor).

Good luck, and please let us know if you have any success.

Answer (score 0):

use this jquery .....

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
        $this.remove();
});
```